# Crontab at specific time oneliner

Tags: cron

I need to run job daily at 10, 12, 16 and 20 hours.
I know that I can create 4 cron jobs like this:

```
0 10 * * * /path/to/execute/file
0 12 * * * /path/to/execute/file
0 16 * * * /path/to/execute/file
0 20 * * * /path/to/execute/file
```

I'm curious, is it possible to arrange this tasks in single cron task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible:

`0 10,12,16,20 * * * /path/to/execute/file`

Here's a quick tutorial for better working with [cron](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm)